# Error: withCallingHandlers crashing R

Tags: r, plyr

I've been using plyr-based function `summarySE` and `ddply` for several months without any problem. Today when I ran my extremely basic routine in R some error message showed up and made R crash.

Here is an example code and the error I get before R crashes:

```
install.packages("plyr")
library(plyr)
results<-data.frame(Depth=rbind("Surface","Bottom"),DO=(runif(10,4,6)))
ddply(results, .(Depth), summarise,
mean = round(mean(DO), 2),
sd = round(sd(DO), 2),
min = min(DO),
max = max(DO))
```

`Error in withCallingHandlers(tryCatch(evalq((function (i):`
`object '.rcpp_warning_recorder' not found`

I read that `withCallingHandlers` is a function to deal with error messages, it shouldn't give me any error during ddply usage. Does anyone know how to fix it?
I have tried reinstalling `plyr` but had no success on this issue.
It was working 14 hours ago, therefore this error makes no sense at all to me...
Thanks!

Edit: I have also tried to install `plyr`from the source as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19933333/error-thrown-within-ddply-crashes-r) but it didn't work as well, I still get the same error message.

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19933333) - I had this exact error this morning, and the answer to the above question by yoplait worked for me

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work for me...

Comment: just noticed the error also applies for ggplot

Comment: I guess the problem was something related to `Rcpp` package. After reinstalling and trying to update it, ddply worked perfectly again today.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I updated the package "Rcpp" and now it is working for me. install.packages("Rcpp")

Comment: This should've been a comment on the question, not an answer.

Comment: @BrianRay Does seem to be the actual answer though, looking at dudu's own comment to his question!

Answer (score 5):

This looks to be an issue where the version of Rcpp on your system is older than the version running on CRAN. In this case upgrading the Rcpp package on your system via install.packages("Rcpp") (as others have mentioned) should solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same error message whenever I called ggplot. If updating Rcpp doesn't work, update to R version 3.2.2 - that should solve it.