# How to Split-Apply-Combine for several variables / columns in R

Tags: r, plyr, split-apply-combine

I'd like to perform a function on several variables, by group.

Fake data;

```
df<-data.frame(rnorm(100,mean=10), 
               rnorm(100,mean=15),
               rnorm(100,mean=20),
               rep(letters[1:10],each=10)
               )
colnames(df)<-c("var1","var2","var3","group1")
```

In this particular case, I'd like to mean-center each variable by group.  I want to return a dataframe with the original and centered variables.

Normally I use PLYR package for this;

```
library(plyr)    
ddply(df, "group1", transform, centered_var1= scale(var1, scale=FALSE))
```

However, I haven't been able to successfully loop this function, or think of another minimal-code way to do this.

I'm open to non-PLYR solutions...My main criteria is keeping code to a minimum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `colwise` function may be what you're looking for.

```
library("plyr")
ddply(df, .(group1), colwise(scale, scale = FALSE))
```

Comment: I'm splitting hairs, but this answer seems closest to my original question, returns a dataframe object, although still need to `cbind()` to combine old and new variables.  Also need to subset my full dataframe before using this approach.  Anyone know how you could feed ddply just the variables you want to perform the function on (preferably as a character vector)   to avoid having to subset?

Comment: Answering question in my comment above; Can use argument `.cols=`  of `colwise` to feed the function specific variables from the full dataframe. e.g, `.cols=c("var1","var2")`

Answer (score 3):

Using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(group1) %>%
  mutate_each(funs(scale(., scale=F))) -> res
```

Comment: This is making R 3.1.3 on windows 7 crash.  I'm not too familiar with dplyr so I haven't been able to find what is wrong.  Any idea? ..................................................             Error in withCallingHandlers(tryCatch(evalq(scale(c(9.15179348355958,  : 
  object '.rcpp_warning_recorder' not found

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way. Please contact the application's support team for more information.

Comment: @DaveM oh, maybe reinstall Rcpp and upgrade to R 3.2, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28966800/error-withcallinghandlers-crashing-r

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
ddply(df, "group1", transform, centered_var1= scale(var1, scale=FALSE),
      centered_var2 = scale(var2, scale=FALSE),
      centered_var3 = scale(var3, scale=FALSE))
```

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't realize I could keep adding argument for additional variables like that.  Is there a way to automate this, whereby I don't need to enter each variable by hand (i.e., like indexing in a for loop?)